# Installed Tensorflow but it failed to load on Python

Tags: tensorflow

Here is the error I get:
[Error trace is provided](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ekVTn.png)
Python 3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:59:51) [MSC v.1914 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import tensorflow as tf
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "C:\Python3.7.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
> > >           from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
> > >         File "C:\Python3.7.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
> > >           _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
> > >         File "C:\Python3.7.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
> > >           _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
> > >         File "C:\Python3.7.0\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
> > >           return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
> > >         File "C:\Python3.7.0\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
> > >           return _load(spec)
> > >       ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
  File "C:\Python3.7.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 24, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Python3.7.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line 49, in 
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "C:\Python3.7.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 74, in 
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python3.7.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
    from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
  File "C:\Python3.7.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 28, in 
    _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
  File "C:\Python3.7.0\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow_internal', fp, pathname, description)
  File "C:\Python3.7.0\lib\imp.py", line 243, in load_module
    return load_dynamic(name, filename, file)
  File "C:\Python3.7.0\lib\imp.py", line 343, in load_dynamic
    return _load(spec)
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Answer (score 0):

Try checking if tensorflow is really installed by

> pip3 list

if so I recommend you install python 3.7.2.

Make sure you remove the file python from this directory  `C:\Users\Your_user_name\appdata\local\programs\python` before installing the new version of python. I tried it. It's working for me. I hope it helped.